# how to change the background image of button everytime when i clicked on that button

Tags: iphone

Hi I want to make a checkbox field in for that I am using two images checkbox.png and unchecked.png and i want to replace this image every time when user clicks on button. so my question is how to change the background image of button every time when i clicked on that button.

can I do this for that

```
 if ([_arsa1.currentImage isEqual:@"checkbox.png"])
  {
    [_arsa1.currentImage isEqual:@"checkbox_checked-1.png"];
   }
  else
   {
    [_arsa1.currentImage isEqual:@"checkbox.png"];
   }
```

if yes then why this not works and if no then suggest me some other code
Thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked-1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender
{
    if(btn.selected == TRUE)
    {
        btn.selected = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        btn.selected = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> set two images for two controll states(UINormalState and
>   UISelectedState) and simply set selected YES/NO to that button it'l
>   change automatically.

```
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked-1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

-(IBAction)btnAction:(UIButton *)sender{

    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Comment: can you write the complete code for this i am not getting ur point plz

Comment: it gives error on this line   sender.selected = !sender.selected;

Comment: error is "property not found on object of type _strong id".

Comment: show me your button action method and button definition.

Comment: where i have to declared these two lines 
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked-1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *arsa1;
-(IBAction)select1:(id)sender;

Comment: replace  -(IBAction)select1:(id)sender; with  -(IBAction)select1:(UIButton*)sender; in .h and .m file then it'l work. and set images in view didload or willAppear methods.

Comment: actually i have two buttons arsa1 and arsa2 and i want that when i select the arsa1 button then image of arsa1 is changed and arsa2 remains the same while when i select the button arsa2 then image of arsa2 is changed and if arsa1 is already selected then also changes the image to previous image just like we do in check boxes..

Comment: i write this in view did load
 [_arsa1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_arsa1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked-1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [_arsa2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_arsa2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked-1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
and

-(IBAction)select1:(UIButton*)sender
{
    sender.selected=!sender.selected;
}

but its not working friend

Comment: Check IBOutlet Connected or not?